# AWS fargate - pulling from internal (private) repo possible with SSL cert bypass?

Tags: ssl, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I read a lot of the questions and answers about ECS/fargate with private repo,
and I have been assigned to use ECS with our company's internal repo - nexus,
since this Nexus is a HTTPS with a self-sign cert
it seems ECS do not like self-sign cert

Is that any way to bypass the SSL cert check?

error below

CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "/<repo_acc>/:latest": failed to do request: Head https:///<repo_acc>//manifests/latest: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Answer (score 1):

seems other expert n re:post answered my question already, there is no way to bypass via fargate.  I will convenience my team to use ECR to bridge the image to.

https://repost.aws/questions/QU7VYfP92kSkSqQCNsrCb4vw/aws-fargate-pulling-from-internal-private-repo-possible-with-ssl-cert-bypass

***Quoted***

*ACCEPTED ANSWER
There is no way to bypass the SSL certificate check.
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/740*

*Unfortunately, no way to add a private CA certificate is provided either.
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1301*